# onClick not triggered on LinearLayout with child

Tags: android, onclick, android-linearlayout

I've got a custom LinearLayout with a smaller TextView child. I'd like to be able to click the area not covered by the TextView, so I set clickable=true and an onclicklistener to the LinearLayout, but onClick is not triggered. If I set the onclick listener on the TextView it works as expected...

Anybody can help?

**ar_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ar_item" android:layout_width="202dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp" android:background="@drawable/bg_item_ar"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ar_item_txt"
        android:layout_width="164dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp" android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" android:paddingRight="6dp" android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#50000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My custom LinearLayout**

```
public class ARView extends LinearLayout
{    

    public ARView(final Context context, String name, String id)
    {        
        super(context);  
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ar_item, this ,true);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.ar_item, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ar_item_txt);
        textView.setText(name);

        setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {                   
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "hey!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

for every child

> android:duplicateParentState="true"

Comment: Thanks for this, solved my similar problem of having multiple controls that I want to express a "clicked" visual state, while only having to handle the event in the parent.

Comment: Although I do still see one very strange issue - when I have clickable = true, width/height=wrap/match, it works, but if I put those into a style and use that style, it doesn't (no visual 'clicked' state, no handler fired). This is on 2.3; any idea why that might be occurring?

Comment: Thanks for this!  Solved an issue I was having today with nested linear layout selection.

Comment: @Blackbelt Here in this scenario where i should put this *android:duplicateParentState="true"* ? inside *Linear Layout* or *Text View*.

Comment: @jaydroider on the LL's children, so TextView I suppose

Comment: Sill need to set every child android:clickable="false"

Comment: This doesnt work always .... 
refer this ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/31578111/5886712...

or apply below this to child >
 android:clickable="false"

Answer (score 123):

`android:duplicateParentState="true"` did not help me.

To make your layout clickable with its children you need add this option for every ***child***:

```
 android:clickable="false"
```

Then click handling will go ***up*** to ***parent***.

Comment: Thank you @Yurets it's work like magic. this must be acceptable answer

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me too!

Comment: Yep - worked. My problem was my children were buttons (inherently clickable), so I had to change them to ImageViews. I don't know why I had them as buttons in the first place.

Comment: What if have to have clickable children within layout???

Comment: then you skip setting `android:clickable="false"` for those children. @ekashking

Answer (score 25):

This isn't your case, but I had similar problem with clickable `ViewGroup`. After a hour of looking for solution a found out that I set `android:inputType` to `TextView` inside my `ViewGroup` which was blocking `onClick()` listener (no idea why)

> Don't use `android:inputType` with TextView

Comment: thank you!  I couldn't figure out why my TextView was intercepting clicks.

Comment: This was my issue as well, make sure you don't have inputType or have it set to none! Thanks for posting this

Comment: well nothing worked for me, unless i came across your answer, there was input type for my textview.

Answer (score 10):

Make Your parent LinearLayout's **android:clickable="true"**

Make all of the the childview's **android:clickable="false"**

Under Linearlayout - Remove **android:inputType=""** from TextView

Answer (score 5):

The `android:duplicateParentState="true"` made my **TextView** looks like it's disabled, and cannot receive click event.

All you need is set the **TextView** `clickable="false"`. So the click event will dispatch to parent layout, and the **TextView** still can react to touch event (with ripple effect).

Answer (score 2):

Your TextView height covers the whole parent (whole layout) so you might clicking on empty space but not on the layout. Try using wrap_content for android:layout_height for your TextView. Set click listener for the layout as well.

Comment: The width of the TextView is smaller than its parents, so there should remain a clickable area on the right of the Linearlayout.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using your custom View; you're using a standard LinearLayout. Your XML tag should be:

```
<com.yourcode.ARView ...> ... </com.yourcode.ARView>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to make sure of is that another view is not on top of the view you are trying to click. This is especially common in FrameLayouts (where your sub LinearLayout may be covered) or with Relative Layouts you might have forgot to update this line:

```
android:layout_below="@id/shouldBeTheIdOfTheViewCurrentlyBeingCovered"
```

so that views don't fill the same space.

Answer (score 1):

If the views in question are `TextView`s, you may need to set them as `focusable="false"` so that the first click isn't used focusing on the text view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be from the textview that has `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in its layout. If that doesn't fix the issue, the problem may be the onClick() event. The linear layout may not actually ever call onClick() since its a layout. Try overriding the onTouch() event listener instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attributes to the linearlayout
Any Click events not handled by the child views will be automatically passed over to the LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true">

<child/>
<child/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and all the XML Attributes didn't work. I am not sure if this happens because i programmatically inflate and add the views, but this is how i worked around the problem.

I have a Class which extends LinearLayout, with a TextView and an ImageView.
After inflating the layout and getting the views, I assigned the child views a OnClickListener, when pressed, executes the LineaLayout's onClickListner.

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {
private OnClickListener clickListener;
ImageView imageView;
TextView textView;

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
    super.setOnClickListener(l);
    clickListener = l;
}

void afterViews() {
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            clickListener.onClick(MyView.this);
            return false;
        }
    });
    textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            clickListener.onClick(MyView.this);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I also tried overriding OnTouchListener, but then my child views didn't have the ripple effect, which I needed.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above forked for me. Than i noticed that a `LinkMovementMethod` set to `TextView` inside my `LinearLayout`. This class intercepts touch events, click events and properties of `TextView` such as clickable, focusable vs..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and all the XML attributes didn't work. I think this happens because I programmatically inflate and add the views. The fix for me was to - also that programatically - set the inflated root view not clickable:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, someLinearLayout, false);
view.setClickable(false);
```

(Yes, I tried to have the `some_layout` not clickable in XML.)

Answer (score 0):

`android:duplicateParentState="true"` >= not worked

`focusable="false"` >= not worked

`clickable="false`>= not worked

So i did a quick fix by adding **Transparent Button** on top with **match_parent** for *height* and *width*

Problem solved without any extra code,