# Android: How to propagate click event to LinearLayout childs and change their drawable

Tags: android, onclick, android-linearlayout

I would like to create a linear layout which would behave similarly to ImageButton.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    style="?WidgetHomeIconContainer">            

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        style="?WidgetHomeIcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="?WidgetHomeLabel"             
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/TextHomeLabel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In styles of ImageView, TextView and LinearLayout, I set a selectors for all states.

Now:

- when I click on ImageView (I tried it also with ImageButton) - it behaves correctly and the image is changed according the selector xml.
- when I click on LinearLayout - the linear layout is clicked, but the the ImageView and TextView don't change it's drawable/appearance

So I would like to do the following. When I click on parent LinearLayout, I need to change all it's childs to pressed state.

I tried to add following code to LinearLayout onClickListener to propagate the click:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) v;
    for(int i = 0; i < l.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        l.getChildAt(i).setClickable(true);
        l.getChildAt(i).performClick();
    }
}
```

But it still reamins the same. Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Put

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

in your ImageView and TextView..[then the views get its drawable state (focused, pressed, etc.) from its direct parent rather than from itself.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aduplicateParentState)

Comment: android:duplicateParentState="true" doesn't work for me, any idea why?

Comment: I have the same problem but the click works and the selector doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: Every time I forget how this is done I always end up here. Thank you, sincerely.

Answer (score 8):

Not only make for every child:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

But also additionally:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

This will prevent unexpected behaviour (or solution simply not working) if **clickable child views** are used.

[SO Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31578111/5719764)

Comment: I also had to add `android:focusable="false"` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

After having the same problem some months later, I found this solution:

```
private void setOnClickListeners() {
    super.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick(v);
        }
    });
    for (int index = 0; index < super.getChildCount(); index++) {
        View view = super.getChildAt(index);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick(v);
            }
        });
    }
}

protected void onClick(View v) {
    // something to do here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, no one of the other solutions works!

I finally had to use `OnTouchListener` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375336/2835520), capturing the event when the user clicks in the parent view, and removing all childs `OnClickListener`.

So the idea is, **delegate the click behavior to the parent, and notify the child** that is really clicked, if you want to propagate the event. *¡¡That's what we are looking for!!*

Then, we need to check which child has been clicked. You can find a reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50369796/2835520) to know how it´s done. But the idea is basiclly getting the area of the child, and asking for who contains the clicked coordinates, to perform his action *(or not)*.

Answer (score 1):

At first, my child view failed to get click from parent. After investigating, what I need to do to make it work are:

1. remove click listener on child view
2. adding click listener on parent view

So, I don't need to add these on every children.

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
android:clickable="false"
```

I only add `duplicateParentState` to one of my child view.

My child view is now listening to parent click event.