# View placed below toolbar in AppBarLayout not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The custom toolbar is rendering perfectly below toolbar. It contains 4 LinearLayouts stacked horizontally inside a LinearLayout, each containing an ImageView and a TextView. They represent different sections of the app and I need to make them clickable but I cannot. The Java code is:

```
//MainActivity.onCreate()
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
...
setOnClickListenersOnToolbarItems();
...

private void setOnClickListenersOnToolbarItems(){

        View toolbarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_toolbar, null);

        //LinearLayouts
        View clothingView = toolbarView.findViewById(R.id.clothingView3);
        View sportsView = toolbarView.findViewById(R.id.sportsView3);
        View shoesView = toolbarView.findViewById(R.id.shoesView3);
        View moreView = toolbarView.findViewById(R.id.moreView3);

        clothingView.setOnClickListener(this);
        sportsView.setOnClickListener(this);
        shoesView.setOnClickListener(this);
        moreView.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

I have tried the following things:

1. This is not applicable as it positions my view wrongly:

   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView() 
   //or getCustomView()
2. The top 2 answers to this question did not work:

[onClick not triggered on LinearLayout with child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763876/onclick-not-triggered-on-linearlayout-with-child)

Comment: View clothingView =(View)findViewById(R.id.clothingView3);

Comment: @Divyesh, LinearLayouts are placed inside custom_toolbar.xml, not in main layout

Comment: @Neonamu custom_toolbar is a regular layout with LinearLayout as parent.

Comment: Try to put this <include> inside Toolbar tags, and remember to put  
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)); in your activity, before work with it.

Comment: @Downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a id to your custom toolbar like this

```
     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <include 
           android:id="@+id/mCustomToolbar"
           layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

then in java

```
private void setOnClickListenersOnToolbarItems(){

    View toolbarView = findViewById(R.id.mCustomToolbar);

    //LinearLayouts
    View clothingView = toolbarView.findViewById(R.id.clothingView3);
    View sportsView = toolbarView.findViewById(R.id.sportsView3);
    View shoesView = toolbarView.findViewById(R.id.shoesView3);
    View moreView = toolbarView.findViewById(R.id.moreView3);

    clothingView.setOnClickListener(this);
    sportsView.setOnClickListener(this);
    shoesView.setOnClickListener(this);
    moreView.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```