# Making View clickable, not the Edittext inside the View

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I have an `EditText` that is wrapped in a `TextInputLayout` that is `inside` a `LinearLayout` and I want to show a `fragment` when the `LinearLayout` is `touched`. However the `EditText` is intercepting the `touch`.

I tried setting `focusable="false"` and `clickable="false"` on the `EditText` and the `TextInputLayout` but now the `touch` doesn't do anything except change the hint `color slightly` for a little bit.

I don't want to set `enabled="false"` because of the grayed out `style color` changes.

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/type_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/type_input_layout"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/type_input"
                    android:hint="Type"
                    android:text="Public"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="22sp"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

My solution for now: just put a view on top of the edittext

Answer (score 2):

try this ,may be its working

set in your linear layout

```
 android:clickable="true"
```

set in your editText

```
 android:clickable="false"
 android:focusable="false"
```

remove from TextInputlayout this 2 lines

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:enabled="false"`. I'm not sure but it might work.

Comment: It does not, it also grays everything out which i don't want

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on your LinearLayout to make children view not focusable.

You can also try using both focusable properties

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

**EDIT:**

Try `android:duplicateParentState="true"` for every child view of the LinearLayout. You can also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763876/onclick-not-triggered-on-linearlayout-with-child). There is someone mentioning that `inputType` on EditText can intercept the click.

Comment: Is the EditText still focusable?

Comment: the edittext is not focusable, but I still can't get the LinearLayout's onClick to trigger

Comment: I removed the input type on the edittext and set android:duplicateParentState="true" on the textinputlayout, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In xml for EditText you should declare:

```
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
```

This will make it not able to take over the click.