# What could be responsible for an ImageView not being clickable

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

I am using an `ImageView` as a NEXT button in my Android app which is responsible for loading the next page of results into the current activity.  However, despite that I bind a click listener to it, I cannot seem to capture click events on this `ImageView`.  Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listBackIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back_icon"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listBackLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prev"
        android:textSize="16dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the relevant Java code:

```
ImageView forwardIconView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.listBackIcon);
// not sure if necessary; doesn't fix it anyway
forwardIconView.setClickable(true);
forwardIconView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ++pageNumber;
        try {
            params.put("page", pageNumber);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // do something
        }
        ConnectionTask task = new ConnectionTask();
        task.execute(new String[0]);
    }
});
```

I spent about an hour researching this on Stack Overflow.  I found a few places which claimed that `ImageView` could directly be made clickable, but most things recommended workarounds using other types of widgets.

Does anything about my layout/code stand out as being a culprit for this behavior?

**Update:**

I also tried binding a click listener to the `TextView` at the same level as the `ImageView` and this too failed to capture clicks.  So now I am suspecting that the views are being masked by something.  Perhaps something is capturing the clicks instead of the views.

Comment: well, i use imageview click offen.. i don't think its usefull to write `forwardIconView.setClickable(true);` .. make sure ur another view is not over it, which taking control and getting onClick event before it..

Comment: @SRBbans Based on the fragment of layout I showed in my question, what could be capturing the click event instead of the two views?

Comment: may be your some other view drawn over it... like dinamic views or something... but invisible and getting the click behaviour. just guessing ..

Comment: have you checked by adding log inside onClick() method?

Comment: Sanity check: are you sure you're looking at/clicking on the right thing? Your description is of a "NEXT" button, and the `ImageView` is `forwardIconView`, but its ID is `listBackIcon`.

Comment: Try to debug it and check if it reaches the onClickListener, if not, maybe it is a layout or view issue.

Comment: It is the correct thing and elsewhere in the same activity I successfully bind a click listener to other text views.  I will try to see what is covering these image views.

Comment: A quick test to check if those are indeed being covered would be to temporarily replace one of those `View` types with `Button`, and see if you get any visual feedback when clicking. Beyond that, ya know, mcve.

Comment: @MikeM. I just took your advice and added a button, and it _does_ respond when clicked.

Comment: What happens when you set an `OnClickListener` on it? Actually, how were you determining that the `OnClickListener` on the `ImageView` wasn't working? Did you put a break point there, or use a log print or `Toast` or something?

Comment: @MikeM. I actually added a listener to the button, and it worked.  But the listeners and text and image views do not work.  Strange.  I suspect that the layout containing them is eating the events.  Maybe the layout width of `0dp` is somehow responsible.

Comment: Nah, the 0 width just means the parent `LinearLayout` should use the weight to determine the actual width. If you can see the child `View`s, it doesn't really have 0 width. You say you _added_ a `Button`? What happens if you just directly change `<ImageView` to `<Button` for `listBackIcon` in the layout? Does that respond? (Change the type in the code, too, btw, or you'll crash.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seemed to work for me was the accepted answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763876/onclick-not-triggered-on-linearlayout-with-child), which suggests adding the following the every child element of the `LinearLayout` which I pasted in my question:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

I don't know exactly what was happening, but it appears the click events were not making it down to the `TextView` and `ImageView`.  Strangely, the click events *were* reaching a `Button`, when I added one for debugging purposes.  If someone has more insight into what actually happened, leave a comment and this answer can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up like this:

```
private ImageView nextButton;
nextButton = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.back_button);
```

Util.loadImage(getActivity(),R.drawable.some_image,nextButton); //Here i would load the image, but i see you do it in XML.

```
 nextButton.setOnClickListener(nextButtonListener);

 nextButton.setEnabled(true);

 View.OnClickListener nextButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    Log.v(TAG, "ImageView has been clicked. do something.");

    }
};
```

This works for me.

Comment: This may work for you, but it wasn't working for me, this is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `android:drawableLeft` attribute for the textview instead of using `imageView`​ and `textview` both in a `linearlayout` .

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listBackIcon"
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
```

Or you can try overriding `onTouchListener` with `ACTION_DOWN` event filter, not `onClickListener`. Also check for parrents with `android:clickable="false"`, they could block childs for click events.

Comment: I will check the `clickable` properties of parents, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, notice that your views can take focus and your wanted view can get it back if you have a very loaded view. Also try using an `ImageButton` instead `ImageView`. Also you can listen to your `LinearLayout` parent by making it `clickable=true` and his childs unclickables.