# How to make Layout clickable which has disabled EditText and Button

Tags: android

I have simple layout with EditText and a button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want EdiText to be editable and want to handle click on complete layout

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.linearLayout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but it is not working I mean There is no Toast message when I am clicking.

Comment: What "is not working"?

Comment: There is no Toast message when I am clicking.

Comment: Post more of your class. Are you inflating this layout?

Comment: are you clicking the button or the layout?

Comment: You can add one more attribute to button `android:clickable="false"` and check the result

Comment: android:clickable="false" with this attribute only Button side of part is working(I can show toast) still EditText side part is not working.

Comment: @bensadiku there is nothing much code. For posting here I have created a sample app. I have added complete MainActivity code.

Comment: you want the toast to appear when the 'edittext' is clicked?

Comment: expected behaviour is anywhere on LinearLayout you click, toast should come.

Comment: @Vivart i edited my answer for the EditText too

Answer (score -1):

as @Liem Vo said in the comments: you should add `android:clickable="false"` to the button, and make sure not to add a click listener in java.
becuse the event is handled by the child view.

for the 'EditText' you can call the parents click listener manually:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View parent = (View) v.getParent();
            parent.performClick();
        }
    });
```

please refer to this question: [onClick not triggered on LinearLayout with child](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6763876/3220968)