# Android button not clickable when turning visible

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-button

Hi Im posting this after not finding any possible answer here.

I have an invisible LinearLayout LL1 in a fragment that I turn visible when a recylerView data is empty, that LL1 has a button on it. The problem is simply that the button is not clickable ! I tried setting the listener in different ways but still not working. Here's the code below:

Here's the xml file:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.main.MainActivity"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/msg_emty_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_box" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Aucune vente n'a été trouvée !"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/greydark"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddSale"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Créer une vente"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
            android:background="@drawable/centre_button">

        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_db"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_sale_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_db"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccesGreen"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here's the java:

```
   private void generateSaleList(ArrayList<Sale> saleArrayList, View view) {
    if(saleArrayList.isEmpty()){
        getActivity().setTitle("Ventes sur portable");
        msgLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        creatSaleBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddSale);
        creatSaleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        creatSaleBtn.setClickable(true);

    }else{
        msgLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView_db = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_sale_list);
        adapter_db = new SaleAdapter((ArrayList<Sale>) Utils.sortArray(saleArrayList),this,1,getContext(),this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView_db.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView_db.setAdapter(adapter_db);
        adapter_db.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Do you guys see what's causing this weird problem ?

Comment: why you add `creatSaleBtn.setClickable(true);` do you disabling it anywhere? i mean use `creatSaleBtn.setClickable(false);` in other places of code?

Comment: No, I just wanna make sure that it's clickable, and yes I tried it without setClickable

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [**`requestFocusFromTouch()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestFocusFromTouch())

> Call this to try to give focus to a specific view or to one of its
>   descendants.

```
 msgLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 creatSaleBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddSale);
 creatSaleBtn.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Comment: @noah_abou https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763876/onclick-not-triggered-on-linearlayout-with-child

Comment: @noah_abou add `msgLayout.invalidate();`

Comment: The  android:duplicateParentState="true" mentionned in the link did not work

Comment: about msgLayout.invalidate() I tried it, did not work either.. something is wrong somewhere I couldn't find it..

Comment: @noah_abou seems like sloppy mistake costs you

Answer (score 0):

SwipeRefreshLayout's visibility should be GONE after recyclerview is empty.
of coarse recyclcerview is empty but it is still visible so your click events are caught by SwipeRefreshLayout witch is defined on top of LL1.

**EDIT**
instead of recyclerview, set swipe_refresh_db visibility to gone cos I doubt recyclerview is a child of swipe_refresh_dd so if you set recyclerview's visibility to gone, swipe_refresh_db is still visible and gets click events.
give it a try

Comment: The AddSaleButton and the Fab have different listeners so nope not that, and just to be sure I removed the FAB and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hide your RecyclerView when there's no items (set visibility to gone). The problem is that it's capturing the clicks, since it's placed on top of the button.

Answer (score 0):

as u said in comments you not using `creatSaleBtn.setClickable(false);` anywhere, then you have to hide the `recyclerView` using `recyclerView_db.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

why? because it by default fits the full-screen due too `match_parent` for width and height.

please add `recyclerView_db.setVisibility(View.GONE);`  in the `saleArrayList.isEmpty()` check

so your new code will be :

```
if(saleArrayList.isEmpty()){
    recyclerView_db.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    getActivity().setTitle("Ventes sur portable");
    msgLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    creatSaleBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddSale);
    creatSaleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    creatSaleBtn.setClickable(true);

}
```

Comment: did you try to hide the swipe refresh view?